# Google Maps v3 - Setting bounds to center of markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Despite spending all day searching and trying numerous code methods I am still having problems with trying to center and zoom a google map correctly.

I wonder if someone would be so kind as to point out the obvious as to what Im doing wrong in my code.  Everything worked fine in v2 but Im having difficulty updating to v3.

For information
The map is a small part of a much larger php application, and the needed lat & long map parameters have already been obtained by other methods which are used in the main prog and declared as follows:-

```
var myDestination=new google.maps.LatLng(e_lat,e_long);
var myHome=new google.maps.LatLng(h_lat,h_long);
```

Everything seems to be working ok aside from the zoom and center.
Problematic Code is as follows:-

```
function initialize()
{

// set the map properties
var mapProp = {
  center:myHome,
  zoom:12,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

// set the home marker
var marker_home=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myHome,
  icon:'house.png'
   });

  marker_home.setMap(map);

//set the destination marker  
var marker_destination=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myDestination,
  icon:'flag_red.png'
  });

  marker_destination.setMap(map);



//google polyline between the 2 points 
 var myPolyline = [myDestination,myHome];
 var directPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path:myPolyline,
  strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:0.8,
  strokeWeight:2  
});

directPath.setMap(map);


//  Make an array of the LatLng's of the markers you want to show
var LatLngList = array (new google.maps.LatLng (e_lat,e_long), new google.maps.LatLng  (h_lat,h_long));
//  Create a new viewpoint bound
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
//  Go through each...
for (var i = 0, LtLgLen = LatLngList.length; i < LtLgLen; i++) {
//  And increase the bounds to take this point
bounds.extend (LatLngList[i]);
}
//  Fit these bounds to the map
map.fitBounds (bounds);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

TIA for any help :)

Comment: What is it doing? Do you get any javascript errors?  Since you only have 2 points, it should work without the loop.  Can you provide a link to a map that exhibits the problem (or create a jsfiddle that does)?

Comment: It seems to be displaying ok..  just that the fitBounds doesnt appear to work and therefore not centering correctly between the two points.

http://jsfiddle.net/klaw/tQf9n/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code "array" is not defined. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tQf9n/1/).

```
var LatLngList = array (new google.maps.LatLng (e_lat,e_long), new google.maps.LatLng  (h_lat,h_long));
```

You should use

```
var LatLngList = new Array(new google.maps.LatLng...)
```

or

```
var LatLngList = [new google.maps.LatLng...]
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply I have replaced

    var LatLngList = [
   [ new google.maps.LatLng(e_lat,e_long)],
   [ new google.maps.LatLng(h_lat,h_long)]
   ];

But it is still exhibiting the same behaviour and still not constraining the 2 points within the bounds and the map is not fitting to the correct zoom nor centering midpoint between Home and Destination. :/

Thank you for you help and advice so far..

Comment: `var LatLngList = [new google.maps.LatLng(e_lat, e_long), new google.maps.LatLng(h_lat, h_long)]`

http://jsfiddle.net/tQf9n/4/

Comment: YAY!   Thank you so very much for helping such a n00b.
That sorted it and its now centering perfectly.